# Cordova Crosswalk WebView stuck

Tags: android, cordova, webview, remote-debugging

I have a cordova application running on android devices.
There I use [cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview](https://github.com/crosswalk-project/cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview).

I had quite a lot of devices running over the weekend for testing and two devices seemed to have frozen.
The webview has dynamic content, like the current time and date and this was stuck on some time on the weekend.

I then connected to the devices via ADB to check what was wrong. In logcat I saw that the application was still running, so I set up remote debugging in chrome and saw that the application was still working, doing requests. The html was there. I am even able to use the javascript console. I didn't find any errors in logcat as well.

The only problem is I cannot see anything happening. The screencast in the chrome remote debugger is also blank. See picture.

[image]

Usually I am able to see the screencast. Has anyone ever have something like this happen before? Or knows how it could happen that the screencast is blank?

Relevant part of `config.xml`:

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview" spec="~2.2.0">
    <preference name="XWALK_VERSION" value="22+" />
    <preference name="XWALK_LITEVERSION" value="xwalk_core_library_canary:17+" />
    <preference name="XWALK_COMMANDLINE" value="--disable-pull-to-refresh-effect --disk-cache-size=1024 --disable-cache-size=1024" />
    <preference name="XWALK_MODE" value="embedded" />
    <preference name="XWALK_MULTIPLEAPK" value="true" />
</plugin>
<engine name="android" spec="~6.1.0" />
```